# How to get input from user(text) when he presses a button(using a popup window) and save the data to a db?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, mysqli

I am building a site in which users have the ability to write post's and other users could comment on these posts.

By now I managed to create a div that contain the comment's that are posted, I have a "Like" button(not functional at this moment) and I have a "Comment" button that I want to trigger a small window that will open to recieve text from the user(the comment) and add it to my comment table(tblcomments).

The comment button has the same ID of the post it refers to(I built it that way when I echo'ed the page from php and everything sits in the same div). but I can't seem to find a way to pop-up that comment window to recieve the comment from the user and update my table with a comment for this specific post.

The section of the page that contains the comments is being refreshed every 5 seconds so adding a simple text field to the div is imposible cause it will get reset every 5 seconds.

that is how it looks on the page right now:
[image]

And that's the code that generate each and every post like this one on my main page while querying my DB:

```
<?php

include 'connectDB.php';
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
$hash = mysqli_escape_string($conn,   $_SESSION['login_user']);

$resultfr = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT distinct U.userName,concat(U.firstName,' ',U.lastname) as fullName FROM tblUser U inner join tblfriendswith FW on FW.userName1=U.userName or FW.userName2=U.userName where U.userName!='$hash'");
$uName="";
if($resultfr!= FALSE){
  while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultfr)){
    $uName= $uName.$row2['userName']." ";
}
}

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT  U.userName,concat(U.firstName,' ',U.lastname) as fullName,MONTHNAME(P.postDate) as dateM, DAY(P.postDate) as dateD, YEAR(P.postDate) as dateY, P.postID, P.content FROM tblUser U inner join tblPost P on P.userName=U.userName where U.userName in ('$uName','$hash') order by P.postDate desc");
    if($result!= FALSE){
      echo "<div class='forPosts'>";
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $fullName    = $row['fullName'];
        $day=$row['dateD'];
        $month=$row['dateM'];
        $year=$row['dateY'];
        $content   = $row['content'];
        $postID=$row['postID'];
        echo "<div class=\"divStyle2\"><span class=\"myText2\">Posted by " .$fullName." - ".$day." ".$month." ".$year."</span><br><div class=\"divStyle\">".$content."</div>";
        echo "<br><button class=\"myButton\">  <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-heart pull-left\"></span>&nbspLike</button>&nbsp &nbsp<button class=\"myButton\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-comment pull-left\"></span>&nbsp Comment</button>&nbsp &nbsp<button class=\"myButton\" name=\"clickB\" id=\"".$postID."\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom pull-left\"></span>&nbsp Show/hide comments</button></div>";
        //echo "<p class=\"alignW\"><input  class=\" col-sm-5\" type=\"text\" name=\"comment\" id=\"".$postID."\" placeholder=\"Write a comment\"></div>";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT  C.postID, C.commentID, C.userName, C.content,concat(U.firstName,' ',U.lastname) as fullN,MONTHNAME(C.commentDate) as dateM, DAY(C.commentDate) as dateD, YEAR(C.commentDate) as dateY FROM tblUser U inner join tblComment c on U.userName=C.userName where C.postID=$postID order by C.commentDate desc");
        if($result2!= FALSE){
          echo"<div class='forComments'>";

          while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
            $fullN    = $row2['fullN'];
            $day2=$row2['dateD'];
            $month2=$row['dateM'];
            $year2=$row2['dateY'];
            $content2   = $row2['content'];
            echo "<div class=\"divStyle2\" id=\"".$postID."\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-comment\" ></span><span class=\"myText3\">&nbsp" .$fullN. " : ".$content2."</span></div>";
          }
        }echo"</div>";


      }
      echo "</div>";
        }





        echo" <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){";
        echo"   $(\"button[name=clickB]\").click(function() {
             link = $(this).attr('id');
             $('div[id=\"'+link+'\"]').toggle();
             $(\"span\", this).toggleClass(\"glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top\");
           });";
           echo"}); </script>";

?>
```

I use mysqli and xampp.

I would be grateful if someone could help me to achieve my task.

Thank you!

Tom

Comment: I think you should try Bootstrap model for achieving your requirement. You can get idea from http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp .

Comment: that's pretty much like telling me to go and read a book..